# How to respond to an improperly closed question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I am referring to https://stackoverflow.com/q/11064716/390153.

The question was a little clumsy, but reasonable and amenable to a direct answer. I demonstrated this by answering it. However even before I viewed the question it had received downvotes by several people who clearly lacked the necessary expertise and background knowledge to understand the question. Unfortunately, some of these individuals had sufficient reputation to vote to close the question. (in particular @marc_s, who showed a spectacularly uninformed understanding of the question in his comment).

I believe closing this question was grossly unfair to the new user.

Is there an appropriate avenue to request review by suitably experienced moderators?

Comment: You answered it and it helped. Where is the harm?

Comment: As for the comments being "ignorant", I place blame squarely on the op's head for that.

Comment: I consider it rather unfair and unwelcoming for a new user to have their question closed like this.

Comment: Are you kidding me? That user has a homework question and is asking us to fill in the blanks for him. That's a horrible question, and is a horrible effort on his part. Answering that type of question is not what we do here. Spend your time fighting worthier battles. But to answer your question, check out *all the related questions* to the side as to how to combat closures you disagree with.

Answer (score 10):

> it had received downvotes by several people who clearly lacked the necessary expertise and background knowledge to understand the question

No, it received downvotes because it's a bad question, as per the hover title for downvoting:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

It was closed as *not a real question* because of this as well. The OP has shown no effort in trying to solve the problem himself. It's just "here is the question." This is a place to ask questions about **specific problems you're facing**, not to just post a homework problem and let someone else explain it to you. If the OP had explained a problem he was having in trying to figure it out, it would have been more acceptable.

Also, going off calling people "uninformed and ignorant" isn't going to get you anywhere here. Just because it's clear to one person doesn't mean it's clear to everyone.

Comment: The first comment on a question on transaction theory asked the questioner to include "what database you are talking about". If that doesn't qualify as ignorant, I don't know what does. While I acknowledge it wasn't a great question, I have seen many much worse upvoted. The question was reasonably clear, as evidenced by the fact I could answer it. The question was a little vague, hence I had to ask for a clarification on one point. The question did show some signs of research, in the reference to Dirty Read, although that indicated the questioner needed the help.

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer your question; users with the same reputation requirements as those who closed the question could vote to reopen it.

The question could be edited, which would *bump* it and bring it to the attention of potential voters-to-reopen.

I would guess it won't get (m)any such votes, though.